# Does "GetGlobalAddressList" retrieve from the remote Exchange server or my local cached copy?

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

If I run this VBA subroutine:

```
Public Sub ViewOutlookGlobalAddressListEntries()

    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olNS As Object
    Dim olGAL As Object
    Dim olEntries As Object
    Dim olMember As Object

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olGAL = olNS.GetGlobalAddressList

    Set olEntries = olGAL.AddressEntries

' Loop through and display entries
    For Each olMember In olEntries
        Debug.Print olMember
    Next olMember

End Sub
```

I see a list of all email address names in my Global Address List. However, I'm not sure if this is retrieving those names from the Exchange server or from my local cached copy of the Global Address List (located at `C:\Users\<my username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook`).

I would like to run a variant of this subroutine everyday so I can update a database with any changes to the Global Address List. However, I don't know if this subroutine will be retrieving the live data from Exchange or the old data from my local cached copy of the global address list.

If it is retrieving from my local cached copy, is there any way to use VBA to update my local cached copy before I put the data in the database? (To manually update it, I would go to Outlook 2013, click File > Account Settings > Download Address Book)

*Update*

Well I unplugged my computer's network connection and ran the subroutine . It still worked fine so it looks like GetGlobalAddressList retrieves from my locally cached copy of the Global Address List. Now I'll just need to figure out how to programmatically update this locally cached copy of the address list first before updating these values in the database

Answer (score 0):

If your profile is cached (uses OST file), GAL is stored locally. If it is online ("Use Cached Mode" is unchecked), all data comes from the server.

Note that it can take Outlook up to 24 hours to download the latest GAL changes from the server.